# Constructing a polygon (hexagon) given length of one side, 2 points and the perimeter?

Tags: algorithm, spatial, polygons

I have a general question on an algorithm that I would like to use to construct an irregular polygon.

I have the following scenario:
I have a start and end position for a ship, thus I know the distance between the two position (say 40km). Using this info, I would like to calculate the remaining vertices of a polygon that includes this as one side, while the other sides should be equal in length and sum up to say 200km (as a matter of fact, any user supplied length). I therefore know the perimeter of the resulting polygon and the 2 vertices that make up one of the sides.

In short, how do I get the other 4 vertices so that each side besides the initially calculated is the same size (and the perimeter of the hexagon adds up to 200 + initial side)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The interior angles of a regular hexagon are 120 degrees, if that helps.

Comment: Assuming you are talking about a hexagon, you need to make sure that the distance between the two known vertices P0 and P1 is 40 km and you need one more condition to decide which side of P0P1 the hexagon will be in. Then, you can try to find the coordinates of the other 4 vertices.